# Simple Rail Input to instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the form below. I instantiate @month @month = ' ' and  my collection is a list of months I want to show the selected month and display it below. I am thinking I need to refresh the page or else use ajax. When I refresh the page I loose the @month - if I ever had it

How do I do this?

```
= simple_form_for @month, html: { :class => 'form-inline' } do |f|
    = f.input :month, label: 'Report Month', collection: month_select
  = submit_tag 'refresh', class: 'btn btn-mini'
.row
.span11
%h4 The number of different Households served during: #{@month}
```

Comment: Can you include your controller code?

Comment: You may have hit on the key point  ! I don't have @month or month in the controller I just use it to allow the user to input a month that is used as a scope for the date field: visited_on so I can generate a report for visits in a particular month